# Ant and .NET and TFS will it all work together?

Tags: .net, ant, tfs, continuous-integration

Does Ant work with .NET and TFS?  Can I hire a guy who knows this an have all my builds be automated?  Are there any down sides?

Comment: If you're in .NET why do you not want to use MsBuild?  The .csproj files are already de facto build scripts for that environment.

Comment: Are you building Java code with ant?  Or are you building C# code with nant?

Comment: If you're using TFS2010, then it's trivial to create an automated build. It's nothing like as difficult as with Ant or even MSBUILD. For most build requirements, "it just works".

Comment: I am asking because we have Java here too and they wanted to see if they could hire one NANT guy for it all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating maintaining an Ant build file (technically it would be NAnt) would be extra work and a source of friction.  You can create an NAnt build script to perform extra tasks and still use MSBuild to build your project, but this should be unnecessary if you are using TFS.